# Multimedia library for Java

Tags: video, java

Are there any libraries to play media, such as video or audio, in Java 6 and onwards? As far as i can tell, JMF is from Java 2 and there dont seem to be any alternatives.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Although I'm not a Java developer I'd recommend at least answering: Do you want/need it to be Open Source? What mime-types do you need to be able play?

Comment: What is wrong with the solution(s) you have tried so far? Also, do you need to support any patent-encumbered format/codec?

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework#Alternatives) has an Alternative section of JMF. As far as I can tell JMF has some problems on handling various newer formats. I would suggest to use equivalent libraries to the kind of multimedia you want to process.
For example:
 For handling audio files use implementations of the [Java Sound API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html) such as [JavaLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) and/or [MP3SPI](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html).
For playing videos you can use an embedded vlc player API such as [this](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj).(Those options mentioned are free and open-source, I imagine there are other proprietary libraries which might suit you better)

**NOTE:** I thought java7 has a media API but I'm having a hard time to find and use it as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693753/what-happened-to-java-media-components).

Hope I helped a little!